# /usr/bin/mysqld_safe not found

Tags: mysql, docker, syslog, rsyslog

I have pulled up latest mysql docker image on centos 7 and ran it. Now I want to change the configuration /etc/my.cnf to make all mysql logs redirected to syslog for consumption.

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#usual configurations
..
[mysqld_safe]
syslog
syslog-facility = local3
```

However I dont see mysqld_safe command available to me with installation neither have it running when I start mysqld.

```
[root@4b0bb3cd16c6 builder]# /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
bash: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: No such file or directory
```

What additional steps/setup do I need to perform for enabling mysqld_safe running ? Without this I dont think my mysql log forwarding to syslog can happen.